# Make Twitter Bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click easily (solution)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hover, dropdown

I want to my toggle dropdown button show the dropdown menu on hover rather than click. To do that i use the bootstrap method `$().dropdown('show')`. What did you thinking about?

```
  $(document).on("mouseenter", "#dropdown-menu-button", (e) => {
    $(e.currentTarget).dropdown('show');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are listening for 'onmouseover' event. So it fires soon as you move mouse to the element. So it opens the dropdown. But also you need to listen for 'onmouseleave' event.. So that you can hide the dropdown when mouse leaves.

```
$(document).on("mouseleave", "#dropdown-menu-button", (e) => {
    $(e.currentTarget).dropdown('hide');
  });
```

However, the best approach will be using hover() method, provided by jquery. It will bind listeners for both mouseover and mouseleave events.

```
$('#dropdown-menu-button').hover(function(){
    $(this).dropdown('show');
}, function(){
    $(this).dropdown('hide');
});
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it fixed your issue. Thanks